# jQuery replace character in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

here is my table

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>"James"</td>
    <td>"do"</td>
    <td>"you</td>
    <td>"like</td>
    <td>"your life"</td>
  </tr>
</table>


<button>Let the magic begin</button>
```

Id like to remove all ocurences of **"** symbol so `<td>"James"</td>` will be `<td>James</td>` etc.

I created this functions but this do nothing.

```
$("button").on( "click", function(e) {
  $('table').find("tr").each(function() {
      $(this).replace(/\+/g, '');

    });
});
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to actually target the quote in your regex

```js
$("button").on( "click", function(e) {
    $('table tr td').text(function(_,txt) {
        return txt.replace(/\"/g, '');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>"James"</td>
    <td>"do"</td>
    <td>"you</td>
    <td>"like</td>
    <td>"your life"</td>
  </tr>
</table>


<button>Let the magic begin</button>
```